# How to import code to ipython effectively from a github

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, ipython, scikit-learn

So I am relatively new to coding and python, and I am trying to follow examples and tutorials on youtube to help me learn more. Currently I am watching and following this tutorial "[Intro to scikit-learn](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX4ZirOiWkw)"

I have visited the supplied github (something else I am new to) and attempted to load the contents of the github file in Ipython but to little effect. I was wondering if anybody could provide some assistance or instructions on how to do this?

[Here is a link](https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_scipy2013/blob/6fab3e5394d653f44a72c572e7ee7920c513b36b/notebooks/06.1_validation_and_testing.ipynb) to the github in question.

Comment: 1. What is your code 2. do you want to clone the git repository, do you want to download the current state of the master branch do you want to download a file fron github?

Comment: Whilst following the example, i ran into some issues getting my code to repeat exactly what the video's code was achieving. So I thought if I could input the code directly from the github, I may be able to get it working and identify why my attempt was not working.

Answer (score 4):

Below aproximate scenario:

```
In [1]: !git clone your_desired_project
In [2]: import sys
In [3]: sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/folder')
In [4]: import desired_module
```

Instead of `In [2, 3]` you can

```
In [2]: %cd /path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just clone the git repository and launch IPython from the notebooks folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_scipy2013.git
cd sklearn_scipy2013/notebooks
ipython notebook
```